# Explode Array from Repeatable Custom Field

Tags: functions, customization, array

I have an array from repeatable custom field. When I print with vardump the output is...

```
var_dump($affman);
```

this is the result ...

```
 array(3) {
    [0] => array(4) {
        [0] => string(74) "Crak Affiliates|affiliate@example.com|N/A|418-977-3169|crak_affiliates" 
        [1] => string(0) "" 
        [2] => string(0) "" 
        [3] => string(0) ""
    } [1] => array(4) {
        [0] => string(74) "Crak Affiliates|affiliate@example.com|N/A|418-977-3169|crak_affiliates" 
        [1] => string(0) "" 
        [2] => string(0) "" 
        [3] => string(0) ""
    } [2] => array(4) {
        [0] => string(74) "Crak Affiliates|affiliate@example.com|N/A|418-977-3169|crak_affiliates" 
        [1] => string(0) "" 
        [2] => string(0) "" 
        [3] => string(0) ""
    }
}
```

I want to explode every entry and customize the output to the list...

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$affman = get_post_meta($post->ID, "affiliatemanager", false); 
if ($affman[0]=="") { ?>

<?php } else { ?>
<li><u>Finance Manager:</u><br>
<?php foreach($affman as $am) {
$temp = explode("|", "$am");
  $am_name = $temp[0];
  $am_email = $temp[1];
  $am_aim = $temp[2];
  $am_phone = $temp[3];
  $am_skype = $temp[4];
?>

Name: <?php echo $am_name ?>|Email: <?php echo $am_email ?>|AIM: <?php echo $am_aim ?>|Phone: <?php echo $am_phone ?>|Skype: <?php echo $am_skype ?><br>

<?php } ?></li><?php } ?>
```

Above code is failed to show the output I want. Please, help me to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a PHP question than a WordPress question.

Try to replace

```
$temp = explode( "|", $am );
```

with

```
$temp = explode( "|", $am[0] );
```

since `$am` is an array.

You should also consider using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if the array items exists.

Here is one idea:

```
<?php

$affman = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'affiliatemanager', FALSE ); 

if ( is_array( $affman ) ){

    $li = '';
    foreach($affman as $am) {
        $temp = array();

        if( isset( $am[0] ) )
            $temp = explode( '|', $am[0] );

        if( count( $temp ) === 5 ){
            $am_name  = $temp[0];
            $am_email = $temp[1];
            $am_aim   = $temp[2];
            $am_phone = $temp[3];
            $am_skype = $temp[4];
            $li .= sprintf( '<li>Name: %s | Email: %s | AIM: %s | Phone: %s | Skype: %s </li>', 
                            $am_name, 
                            $am_email, 
                            $am_aim, 
                            $am_phone, 
                            $am_skype 
                        ); 
        }
    }
    printf( '<ul>%s</ul>', $li );
}

?>
```